# Let's divide a lattice

Tags: code-golf, sequence, set-partitions

Let's say we have a **n × n** lattice; we can then divide the lattice into two sections by drawing a line through the lattice.  Everything to one side of the line is in one set and everything else in another.

How many ways can we divide the lattice in the manner?

For example lets take a **2 × 2** lattice:

```
. .
. .
```

We can make 2 partitions dividing the lattice in half like so:

```
× ×    × o
o o    × o
```

We can also partition off each of the corners:

```
× o    o ×    o o    o o
o o    o o    × o    o ×
```

Lastly we can put all of the points in one partition by missing the lattice entirely:

```
× ×
× ×
```

This makes for a total of 7 partitions.  Note that the following partition is *not* valid because it cannot be made with a single straight line.

```
× o
o ×
```

Here is a **3 × 3** lattice

```
. . .
. . .
. . .
```

There are 4 purely horizontal or vertical partitions

```
× × ×    × × ×    × o o    × × o
× × ×    o o o    × o o    × × o
o o o    o o o    × o o    × × o
```

There are 4 corner partitions

```
× o o    o o ×    o o o    o o o    
o o o    o o o    o o o    o o o
o o o    o o o    o o ×    × o o
```

There are 4 larger corner partitions

```
× × o    o × ×    o o o    o o o
× o o    o o ×    o o ×    × o o
o o o    o o o    o × ×    × × o
```

There are 8 partitions of partial corners

```
× × o    o × ×    o o ×    o o o    o o o    o o o    o o o    × o o
o o o    o o o    o o ×    o o ×    o o o    o o o    × o o    × o o
o o o    o o o    o o o    o o ×    o × ×    × × o    × o o    o o o
```

There are 8 knights move partitions

```
× × o    o × ×    × × ×    o o o    o o ×    × o o    o o o    × × ×
× o o    o o ×    o o ×    o o ×    o o ×    × o o    × o o    × o o
× o o    o o ×    o o o    × × ×    o × ×    × × o    × × ×    o o o
```

And there is one whole partition

```
× × ×
× × ×
× × ×
```

That makes for 29 partitions in total.

### Task

Given a number **n** as input, output the number of partitions that can be made in this fashion of an **n × n** lattice.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes, with less bytes being better.

### Test Cases

Here are the first 34 courtesy of the OEIS:

```
1, 7, 29, 87, 201, 419, 749, 1283, 2041, 3107, 4493, 6395, 8745, 11823, 15557, 20075, 25457, 32087, 39725, 48935, 59457, 71555, 85253, 101251, 119041, 139351, 161933, 187255, 215137, 246691, 280917, 319347, 361329, 407303
```

[OEIS A114043](http://oeis.org/A114043)

Comment: Can you please add an example with a lattice larger than 2×2?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Added.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>113</s> 111 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to guest44851*

0-indexed.

```js
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i,a)=>a.map((_,j)=>x+=(g=(a,b)=>b?g(b,a%b):a<2&&(n-i-1)*(n-j))(i+1,++j)),x=n*++n)|x+x+1
```

Based on the formula mentioned on OEIS:

> Let V(m,n) = Sum_{i=1..m, j=1..n, gcd(i,j)=1} (m+1-i)(n+1-j)
> a(n+1) = 2(n<sup>2</sup> + n + V(n,n)) + 1

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i,a)=>a.map((_,j)=>x+=(g=(a,b)=>b?g(b,a%b):a<2&&(n-i-1)*(n-j))(i+1,++j)),x=n*++n)|x+x+1

for(n = 0; n < 50; n++) {
  console.log('f(' + n + ') = ' + f(n));
}
```

Comment: You can replace `a==1&&` with `a<2&&`.

Comment: @guest44851 Yes, this one works. :-) Thanks!

Comment: You can also replace `&&x+x+1` with `|x+x+1`.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 59 bytes

```
2Sum[(#-i)(#-j)Boole[i~GCD~j<2],{i,#-1},{j,#-1}]+2#^2-2#+1&
```

courtesy of the OEIS (just like the question)

-1 byte from @ovs

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfKLg0N1pDWTdTE0hkaTrl5@ekRmfWuTu71GXZGMXqVGfqKOsa1upUZ4HpWG0j5TgjXSNlbUO1/wFFmXkl@g5p@g5BiXnpqdGGBrH/AQ)

Comment: This is almost verbatim copied from the OEIS page

Comment: The question is courtesy of the OEIS and so is this answer. An original question would have an original answer

Comment: I don't disagree with you, which is why I didn't downvote, I just prefer transparency.

Comment: Me too! But I think that OEIS-questions is an easy trick to get easy reputation points. That's why I answer in the same way, to state this situation

Comment: You can replace `==1` with `<2` [TIO](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfKLg0N1pDWTdTE0hkaTrl5@ekRmfWuTu71GXZGMXqVGfqKOsa1upUZ4HpWG0j5TgjXSNlbUO1/wFFmXkl@g5p@g5BiXnpqdGGBrH/AQ).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 116 bytes

```python
lambda n:2*(~-n*n+sum((n-i)*(n-j)*g(i,j)for i in range(1,n)for j in range(1,n)))+1
g=lambda x,y:y and g(y,x%y)or x<2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1BCsIwEEX3PcVshJk0BdNlsDdxE6mJE@y0xArJxqvHIG508xcP/ntb2W@rjNVP53p3y2V2IHZU@BpESf94LogyMKm2kVRA1pH8moCBBZKTcEWj5YPiLyLqTRemrzTrYgs4mSFg0flQqD3yqYX/ZeZItgPYEssOHpnqGw)

Comment: `R=range`? Would that save some bytes?

Comment: @Zacharý not with two ranges

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
ạþ`Fgþ`FỊS_²H‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroWH9yW4pYOIh7u7guMPbfJ41DDj////hgYA)

### Explanation

```
ạþ`Fgþ`FỊS_²H‘  Input: integer n
ạþ`             Form the table of absolute differences on [1, 2, ..., n]
   F            Flatten
    gþ`         Form a GCD table on that
       F        Flatten
        Ị       Test if the absolute value of each is <= 1
         S      Sum (Count the number of true's)
          _     Subtract
           ²    Square of n
            H   Halve
             ‘  Increment
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 90 bytes

```python
lambda n:4*n*n-6*n+3+4*sum((n-i)*(n-k/i)for i in range(n)for k in range(i*i)if k/i*k%i==1)
```